# exporting alphanumeric data to excel

Tags: formatting, format, rstudio, xlsx, alphanumeric

I have troubles with formatting after exporting the data frame into excel. I calculate the data and then I use masking formula, to hide some data (using -- signs) if the sample is too low:

```
ValStat <- function(d,a,i,df){
o <- count(d)
per25 <- round(quantile(d$b, probs = 0.25,type = 6),digits = 0)
per50 <- round(quantile(d$b, probs = 0.5,type = 6),digits = 0)
per75 <- round(quantile(d$b, probs = 0.75,type = 6),digits = 0)

df1 <- InitDf(2)
df <- rbind(df, df1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
if(o<22){
df <- FillDf(df,2,i,a,o,"--","--","--")
}
else{
df <- FillDf(df,2,i,a,o,per25,per50,per75)
}
return(df)
}
```

However what I export to excel looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8zhP.png

So the "--" are aligned to the left (as text), and numbers are aligned to the right.
Looks like excel is disregarding my output formats that I use in R code:

```
CellStyle(wb, dataFormat=NULL, alignment=NULL, border=NULL, fill=NULL, font=NULL)
TITLE_STYLE <- CellStyle(wb)+ Font(wb,  heightInPoints=16,  isBold=TRUE, underline=1)
SUB_TITLE_STYLE <- CellStyle(wb) + Font(wb,  heightInPoints=11, isItalic=FALSE, isBold=TRUE)
TABLE_COLNAMES_STYLE <- CellStyle(wb) + Font(wb, isBold=TRUE) +Alignment(wrapText=TRUE, horizontal="ALIGN_CENTER") + 
Border(color="black", position=c("TOP", "BOTTOM"), pen=c("BORDER_THIN", "BORDER_THICK"))
COL_STYLE <- CellStyle(wb) + Alignment(wrapText=FALSE, horizontal="ALIGN_RIGHT")
```

Is there a way to have "--" and numbers formatted in the same manner?
To the right would be great.